# python multiprocessing with boolean and multiple arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a function that takes multiple arguments, some of which are boolean. I'm trying to pass this to the multiprocessing `pool.apply_async` and want to pass some args with the names attached.

Here's an example script that I'm working with:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

    def testFunc(y, x, calcY=True):
        if calcY == True:
            return y*y
        elif calcY == False:
            return x*x

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        p = Pool()
        res = p.apply_async(testFunc, args = (2, 4, False))
        print res.get()
```

This works, but I'm curious about changing the `res = p.apply_async(testFunc, args = (2, 4, False))` to something like:

```
res = p.apply_async(testFunc, args = (2, 4, calcY = False))
```

Comment: have you tried map_async(testFunc, `args=(2, 4), kwargs=dict(calcY=False))`?

Comment: `map_async` takes neither an `args` nor `kwargs` keyword. Your example code should have raised a TypeError.

Comment: @unutbu I'm sorry, that should have been apply_async. I've edited the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[apply_async](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) has `args` and `kwds` keyword arguments which you could use like this:

```
res = p.apply_async(testFunc, args=(2, 4), kwds={'calcY': False})
```