# how do I use key word arguments with python multiprocessing pool apply_async

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool

I'm trying to get to grips with pythons multiprocessing module, specifically the apply_async method of `Pool`.  I'm trying to call a function with arguments and keyword arguments.  If I call the function without kwargs it's fine but when I try to add in a keyword argument I get:
`TypeError: apply_async() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg2'`
Below is the test code that I'm running

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep
def test(arg1, arg2=1, arg3=2):
    sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for t in range(1000):
        pool.apply_async(test, t, arg2=5)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

How can I call the function so that it accepts keyword arguments?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Pass the keyword args in a dictionary (and the positional arguments in a tuple):

```
pool.apply_async(test, (t,), dict(arg2=5))
```

Answer (score 4):

original answer: [python multiprocessing with boolean and multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482592/python-multiprocessing-with-boolean-and-multiple-arguments)

apply_async has args and kwds keyword arguments which you could use like this:

```
res = p.apply_async(testFunc, args=(2, 4), kwds={'calcY': False})
```

Answer (score 1):

Janne's answer didn't work for me in python 2.7.11 (not sure why).
The function test() was receiving the key (arg2), not the value (5).

I fixed this by creating a wrapper around test:

```
def test2(argsDict):
    test(**argsDict)
```

Then calling

```
pool.apply_async(test2, (t,), [dict(arg2=5)])
```

Comment: The thing is, if it is a wrapper, we don't need keyword arguments :) I too confirm the issue of test receiving the key